# get amount of waiting http requests

Tags: node.js, http, express

I am working on an extreme high load web server based on node.js. In my server code, I want to track how many http requests are waiting for handling in every second. Is that possible in node.js?

BTW, my server is running on Mac OS X.

Comment: It is possible, indeed, but you'll have to buy one of [**these babies**](http://www.amazon.com/Digit-Manual-Tally-Mechanical-Counter/dp/B005FUPSKW) to do that !

Comment: I suggest that not to do in server. You cant get some of the information you are looking at by using `JMeter` or similar kind of load test engines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible.

```
var counter = 0

var srv = require('http').createServer(function(req,res) {
   setTimeout(function() {
      res.end("we're serving " + counter + " requests")
   }, 100)
})

srv.listen(1234)

srv.on('connection', function(sock) {
   counter++

   sock.on('close', function() {
      counter--
   })
})
```